# ng-repeat not working when trying to change innerHTML by using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
            app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.data = {"name" : "WW_CIW" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "1" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "2" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "3" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "4" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "5" , "mod" : "WW" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "6" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "7" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "8" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "9" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "10" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "11" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "12" , "mod" : "APS" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "13" , "mod" : "APN" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "14" , "mod" : "APN" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "15" , "mod" : "APN" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "16" , "mod" : "APN" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "17" , "mod" : "APN" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "18" , "mod" : "APN" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "19" , "mod" : "APN" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "20" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "21" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "22" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "23" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "24" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "25" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "26" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "27" , "mod" : "AG" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "28" , "mod" : "EMA" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "29" , "mod" : "EMA" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "30" , "mod" : "EMA" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "31" , "mod" : "EMA" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "32" , "mod" : "EMA" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "33" , "mod" : "EMA" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "34" , "mod" : "EMA" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "35" , "mod" : "OTHER" , "selected" : false},
                    {"name" : "36x" , "mod" : "USERSPACE" , "selected" : false}
            });
            var modlist = [] , submodlist = [];

            function addModule(param) {
                modlist.push(param);
            }

            function addSubModule(param) {
                modlist.push(param);
            }

            function checkModule(param) {
                return modlist.indexOf(param) != -1;
            }

            function checkSubModule(param) {
                return subModlist.indexOf(param) != -1;
            }

            function tester(param) {
                var HTML = '<table border="1"><tr><td>Check</td><td>Submodule</td></tr>';
                HTML += ('<tr ng-repeat="submod in array"><td>' + '<input type="checkbox" name="submodule" value="submod.name"></td><td>{{submod.name}}</td></tr>');
                HTML += '</table>';
                document.getElementById('kya-bakchodi-hai').innerHTML = HTML;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="anApp" ng-controller='aCtrl'>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Check</td>
                <td>Module</td>
                <td>Last Start TS</td>
                <td>Last End TS</td>
                <td>Log</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='module' value='WW'></td>
                <td><a onclick="tester('WW')">WW</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='module' value='EMA'></td>
                <td><a onclick="tester('EMA')">EMA</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='module' value='APN'></td>
                <td><a onclick="tester('APN')">APN</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='module' value='APS'></td>
                <td><a onclick="tester('APS')">APS</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='module' value='AG'></td>
                <td><a onclick="tester('AG')">AG</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='module' value='USERSPACE'></td>
                <td><a onclick="tester('USERSPACE')">USERSPACE</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='module' value='OTHER'></td>
                <td><a onclick="tester('OTHER')">OTHER</a></td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Today</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div id="kya-bakchodi-hai"></div>
    </body>
```

Given my code snippet above, I define my data inside the controller. Inside HTML, when I click on one of the modules inside the table, it should display another table. For that purpose I utilize the `tester()` function inside my script, which substitutes a written HTML snippet into the div I want using `document.getElementById()` .

It should then display the table based on the module selected, for which I use ng-repeat, and I also plan to use ng-if as well. But ng-repeat does not seem to work. Please help.

Comment: if answers of duplicate question by doesn't work for you you can go with this   var h = '<table border="1"><tr><td>Check</td><td>Submodule</td></tr>';
           $scope.data.forEach(e => {
               h += ('<tr><td>' + '<input type="checkbox" name="submodule" 
               value=' + e.name + '></td><td>' + e.name + '</td></tr>');
           });
        h += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('xyz').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", 
         h);
        x = document.getElementById('xyz')
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 500);

Comment: It actually did work for me when I created a new directive and made some necessary changes